# Converting .cdr to shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, standard-license-level

How do I convert a .cdr (Corel) to a shapefile?

I am using ArcMap (ArcEditor) 10.0.  I am brand new to using 10.0 after using 9.3 and brand new to to the ArcEditor level license after using ArcView.

I have never had to work with .cdr before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have CorelDraw Save As DXF in CorelDraw. In ArcGIS you can view DXF natively or import to geodatabase/shapefile. The Corel Draw File (CDR) is a proprietary file format and it is basically a grafic file similar to Adobe Illustrator (AI) files.  Alternatively, if you have AI you can open CDR in AI and Save As DXF then import to ArcGIS. 
You will have to use spatial adjustment to georeference the data if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following tutorials:

[1] https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0103/files/spatools_tutorial.pdf

[2] https://www.wwu.edu/huxley/spatial/tut/adjust.htm